# Use VBA in Excel to Find and Update Related Records on a Different Sheet from Working Sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two spreadsheets. Each spreadsheet contains rows with various bits of information on them, including a unique identifier number (an ISBN in this case).

I am trying to make a script that determines a record is present on the working sheet (obtaining ISBN from column A – working sheet is called ePubWorking), and marks a column (V) on the master sheet (ePubMaster) in the row that contains the same ISBN as found on the previous sheet (the ISBN on the new sheet is also kept in column A). It needs to do this for each record found on the ePubWorking sheet.

I’ve tried a few variants of code I’ve found on here, but I can’t seem to get anything to work. This is what I’m currently working with (which doesn’t appear to be doing anything):

```
 Dim rCell As Range
 Dim rFind As Range
 Dim iColumn As Integer

 For Each rCell In Sheets("ePubWorking").Range("A2", Sheets("ePubWorking").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

  Set rFind = Sheets("ePubMaster").Rows(1).Find(What:=Trim(rCell.Value), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
        rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Sent"

        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
        rFind.Offset(0, 21).Value = "Sent"
        End If
Next rCell
```

Nothing is happening using the above (or any of my other variants). I can't even get the "Sent" part to appear on the secondary sheet.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Go throug your code step by step using F8 and check what the address of `Sheets("ePubWorking").Range("A2", Sheets("ePubWorking").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))` is. Eg use `Debug.Print Sheets("ePubWorking").Range("A2", Sheets("ePubWorking").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Address` to get it (check if it is the reange that you actually planned. • Go further and see what steps are executed if you keep pressing F8.

Comment: This could be probably done with a formula. Is there a reason you need to use VBA?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I run multiple scripts to generate the working sheet, so the form of it changes depending on what stage you are at. A static pull through formula doesn't work for my use case.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for your ISBN in the first row in `ePubMaster`. Are you expecting to find all ISBN's in the first row? Also, if row1 is header, it wouldn't find your ISBN would it?

Comment: @Zac OMG I'm so dumb, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so thanks for the guidance, obviously I'd been banging my head on frankenstein attempts for too long and got blinded to what I was doing. As Zac pointed I was looking along the wrong axis on the ePubMaster sheet.

Working code:

```
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim workingSheet As Worksheet: Set workingSheet = wb.Sheets("ePubWorking")
Dim masterSheet As Worksheet: Set masterSheet = wb.Sheets("ePubMaster")

Dim workingRange As Range: Set workingRange = Range(workingSheet.Range("A2"), workingSheet.Cells(workingSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))

Dim rCell As Range
Dim rFind As Range

For Each rCell In workingRange
    If Not rCell.Value = vbNullString Then
        Set rFind = masterSheet.Rows.Find(What:=Trim(rCell.Value), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)

        rCell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "Sent"

        If Not rFind Is Nothing Then
            rFind.Offset(0, 21).Value = "Sent"
        End If
    End If
Next rCell
```